# How to fix the error of getContext?

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBDON.png)
I am getting the following error of not identifying getContext().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just write :

```
canavas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
```

instead of :

```
canvas = documents.getElementById('gameCanvas');
```

Wrong name. Try to search a little before asking a question